# Signing XML with XADES-BES using Java

Tags: java, xml-signature, xades4j

I could not find a way to sign an XML document by using xades4j library in java. What is the way of creating a signed XML document from an unsigned one?

First of all, I am new in Java programming and I don't know how to create the parameters and the values required in that method:

```
FileSystemKeyStoreKeyingDataProvider(String keyStoreType, String keyStorePath, KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider.SigningCertSelector certificateSelector, KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider.KeyStorePasswordProvider keyStorePasswordProvider, KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider.KeyEntryPasswordProvider entryPasswordProvider, boolean returnFullChain)
```

Is there another way to sign a document easier? If not, what is the true parameters or examples?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the documentation on the project's wiki? In addition, the project's tests include examples on all the features.

If you're new to Java you probably could benefit from reading the JCA guide, namely the [section about key stores](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#KeyManagement). The *FileSystemKeyStoreKeyingDataProvider* class on xades4j is an implementation of [the *KeyingDataProvider* interface](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/providers/KeyingDataProvider.html) that wraps a key store on the file system.

The key store type and path are used as in the *KeyStore* API (refer to the JCA guide and javadocs). The certificateSelector parameter is used to select which certificate/key is used in the signature among the ones in the key store. The other parameters control the passwords for accessing the key store and its entries (may be optional, depending on the key stores. Again, refer to the JCA guide).

To simplify you can just define a class that implements the *KeyingDataProvider* interface by returning constant values. You can add the "real" key stores later when you wrap your head around the API.